# Contenteditable add/remove class if child id :focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div set as contenteditable and everything inside of that div can be edited. Now when I click on the div I automatically add a class selected (If visible prior I remove it and add it to the new selection) I have next and forward buttons so I can change my selection if I'm on using a tablet or smart phone.

Now here's where I need help.

So I selected the middle div and as I move my cursor to another child of `#dynamic-storage` I'm left with the problem of removing the class selected and adding it to the new child that's selected. (Not the span in the example as it's parent is a div. That's what I want selected as the div's in this example are the children of `#dynamic-storage` (ex. `#dynamic-storage > div`)

The snippet provided at the bottom of this post does not contain the arrows or menubar provided in the screenshot and fiddle links above as that code is not necessary at the given time of posting. I'm keeping this post focused on the one task being handling the `.selected` class for the focused child of `#dynamic-storage`.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Select Elements
  var SelectElements = function() {
    $("#dynamic-storage").children().on("mouseup touchend", function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      }

      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
  };
  // Clear Selection
  var ClearSelection = function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  };
  SelectElements();

  // Handles Hotkeys
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // Up & Down Arrow Keys To Select/Deselect Element in Editable
    if (e.which === 38 || 40 )  {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":focus") ) {
        alert("correct");
      } else if ( $(".selected").is(":blur") ) {
        alert("incorrect");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* Body */
#dynamic-storage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

#dynamic-storage .selected {
  outline: 2px dotted #69f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dynamic-storage" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="header" align="center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
        <span>Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div class="header selected" align="left">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="header" align="right">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h5>My name is Michael.</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://liveweave.com/uyz4VK
Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/kujuxofeju/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: maybe the `onfocus` and `onblur` JavaScript events are what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element with attribute `contenteditable='true'` has all its content editable as in a **single** textarea. That is the reason why `focus/blur` event will not happen when you move cursor. Everywhere inside element with `contenteditable='true'` you are still in the same textarea not leaving or entering it.

The solution here is to deal with coursor positioning similar to textarea.

To get an object that represents current selection we use function:

```
var getSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE 9 and non-IE
    getSelection = function() {
        var sel = window.getSelection(), ranges = [];
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
        }
        return ranges;
    };
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    // IE <= 8
    getSelection = function() {
        var sel = document.selection;
        return (sel.type != "None") ? sel.createRange() : null;
    };
}
```

Then we need to do the next operations: remove class `.selected` from the first level children of `#dynamic-storage`, get element with cursor, and go up the DOM to find its parent closest to `#dynamic-storage` to add class `.selected`:

```
// Handles Hotkeys
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // Up & Down Arrow Keys To Select/Deselect Element in Editable
    if (e.which === 38 || 40 )  {
        $('#dynamic-storage > div').removeClass('selected');
        var selectedElem = getSelection()[0].commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;
        $(selectedElem).closest('#dynamic-storage > div').addClass('selected');
    }
  });
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/48tnsoyo/)

Comment: Very informative & instructional. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mikethedj4, I've done some optimization: no Id required for the elements at the bottom of #dynamic-storage.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (try this in your main jQuery function) :

```
$("#dynamic-storage").children().each(function() {
    $(this).on("focus", function() {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).on("blur", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

But if you edit the contents, you will loose the event handlers bound to them ...